# Looking for the function of a curve that starts at 0,0

Tags: graphing-functions

I'm sorry I don't know all the right words to ask...I am a working professional that finished all my math courses decades ago!

I am trying to develop a metric score card for my company's information security program.  I want to gradually increase a score (y value) as more and more devices are out of compliance (x value). In short, I am looking for the function of a curve that starts a 0,0 and goes at least to (or crosses over) 100,100 - [where the curve looks somewhat like a quarter circle - like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6YBv.png).

I feel like the following function is close, but the line is almost linear as the x value increases, which is not what I want.

$y=(x^2/100)$

Comment: How about a perfect quarter circle: $y=-\sqrt{100^2-x^2}+100$?

Comment: @DavidMitra - Sounds like what I am looking for, but that function gives me an inverted parabola when I graph it at https://www.transum.org/Maths/Activity/Graph/Desmos.asp

Comment: The link is the graph of $y=x^2-5$...

Comment: That's the default function the page auto fills out when you arrive on the page.  When I  replace that function with yours in to the graph, it is just an inverted parabola

Comment: Be careful that "$100^2-x^2$" is under the "square root bar" (there probably is some technical term for that).

Comment: Ah, you are right, that was my mistake!  Thank yoU!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation of the quarter-circle like in your picture is $$y=100-\sqrt{100^2-x^2}$$

Comment: Thanks!  That looks about right!

Answer (score 0):

*Welcome to the site !*

Since I suppose that you want that points $(0,0)$ and $(100,100)$ be perfectly reproduced, the simplest model would be
$$y=100 \left(\frac{x}{100}\right)^a$$ Now, you need to tune $a$ using regression.

Comment: Thanks for helping, Claude!  This looks to give me the same curve from the function I listed above.  I think what I am looking for is a line that when it hits 100,100 its going vertical - a line that looks like a like a quarter circle from 0,0 to 100,100.